# How to deal with dependencies in functional tests?

Tags: testing, selenium, junit, functional-testing

Functional tests, unlike unit tests, cannot often be naturally isolated as each test usually requires the state after the execution of the previous one.

For example to test basic CRUD operations like entity deletion or updating it must first be created. While we can prevent code duplication by extracting the code of entity creation into a separate method, it is unclear how to deal with repetition of calling entity creation test or any other dependent tests. And as the number of tests grows these repeated calls significantly degrade time execution and readability.

An intuitive solution would be to merge all these interdependent tests into a single one, but it makes harder to localize a bug.

The information I have read so far was mostly about unit testing and I think it does not perfectly fit the needs for functional/acceptance and especially web browser testing.

To be specific, currently I am using JUnit tests interacting with the webapp with in-memory database via Selenium WebDriver API.

What best practicals some would recommend for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your AUT will provide the ability to create data without excercising the UI. A web service would be great but you could inject directly into the DB (if possible in your case).

The test set up would then create data in the required state via this "backdoor".

The advantage of this is that;

- tests are isolated and have one area if concern
- tests which rely on data can still run even if the UI to enter data is broken

The builder pattern can be used to abstract your data creation (http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html
). This then makes your test set up really expressive and obvious as to the scenario you are trying create and test.

Obviously you may want an E2E test to prove integration between the actions via the UI but this can be restricted to a small subset and then handle any complex scenarios or combinational tests using data creation.

Comment: Good point since modifying state directly is a lot faster to execute. There is an opinion, though, that functional testing is actually "black box" testing, hence touching internals of the application directly in tests is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The best way how you can separate logic of the repeating operations (like CRUD) and tests itself is to use Selenium [Page Objects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects), let me show you an example

```
public class EntityPage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(css = "someLocator")
    private WebElement someElement

    public EntityPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void editEntity(Entity entity) {
        // some WebDriver code to edit entity
    }

    public void addEntity(Entity entity) {}
    // so and so forth...
}
```

Now imagine that every which has something to deal with entities can create instance of this class and easily reuse all these methods for entity manipulation. For instance like this

```
@Test
public void testAddEntity() {
    Entity e = new Entity("name"); 
    EntityPage page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, EntityPage.class);
    page.addEntity(e);
    Assert.assertTtrue(page.isEntityPresent(e));
    page.deleteEntity(e);
}
```

You can see that test became a lot more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes, it is probably the most common way for DRYing up functional tests. But for the second code sample, as I already denoted, putting more actions into one test (addEntity and deleteEntity, etc.) makes it harder to debug.

Comment: Sure, but if you want to emulate user action this would be precisely way to do it. Of course you introduce some boilerplate code but user has to add this entity too in the GUI. So only extra code here is for cleanup.